# O que é WAMP (Web Application Messaging Protocol)?

Tags: terminologia, websocket

Eu tenho estudado um pouco sobre [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) e, ao pesquisar a respeito de como fazer estrutura de canais ou push, me deparei com o termo WAMP.

Ao que me parece, WAMP é um protocolo ou subprotocolo de uma conexão Websocket.

Eu gostaria de saber: O que é detalhadamente o WAMP?

<sub>Não confundir com o software Wamp usado para rodar Mysql, Apache e PHP no Windows.</sub>

Comment: Eu acho que essa nota de rodapé merece um destaque maior. Quase que eu marco como duplicata

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Messaging_Protocol

Comment: Para quem chegar aqui, é desse WAMP que o @WallaceMaxters está falando: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Messaging_Protocol?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Peguei a maior parte da informação que achei sobre isso e traduzi. Conteudo de dificio busca por culpa da ferramenta ja existentes.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado com a edição do título já ajuda

Comment: E quem deu o negativo também poderia esclarecer o que pode ser melhorado!

Answer (score 7):

**Wamp**

WAMP é um subprotocolo do WebSocket registrado na IANA, especificado para oferecer RPC roteado e PubSub. Seu objetivo de design é fornecer um padrão aberto para troca de mensagens em tempo real entre os componentes da aplicação e facilitar a criação de arquiteturas ligeiramente acopladas com base em microservices. É adequado para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos Web responsivos ou para coordenar vários dispositivos conectados no IoT.

**PubSub**

Na arquitetura de software, publish-subscribe é um padrão de mensagens onde os remetentes de mensagens, chamados publishers, não programam as mensagens para serem enviadas diretamente para receptores específicos, chamados subscribers, mas categorizam mensagens publicadas em classes sem conhecimento de quais assinantes. Da mesma forma, os subscribers expressam interesse em uma ou mais classes e somente recebem mensagens que são de interesse, sem conhecimento de quais publishers.

**Subprotocols**

Pense em um subprotocolo como um esquema XML personalizado ou uma declaração de doctype. Você ainda está usando o XML e sua sintaxe, mas você também é restrito por uma estrutura que você concordou. Os subprotocolos do WebSocket são exatamente assim. Eles não apresentam nada extravagante, eles apenas estabelecem estrutura. Como um doctype ou esquema, ambas as partes devem concordar com o subprotocolo; Ao contrário de um doctype ou esquema, o subprotocolo é implementado no servidor e não pode ser encaminhado externamente pelo cliente.

**Fontes**

Wamp - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Messaging_Protocol

PubSub - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

Subprotocols - https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: De onde você está traduzindo? É sempre bom colocar a fonte de pesquisa

Comment: Sem querer eu havia clicado em enviar, antes de terminar minhas tradução. Desculpa, tudo corrigido